# How can I remove or omit data using map method for tf.data.Dataset objects?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.data.dataset

I am using tensorflow 2.3.0

I have a python data generator-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

vocab = [1,2,3,4,5]

def create_generator():
    'generates a random number from 0 to len(vocab)-1'
    count = 0
    while count < 4:
        x = np.random.randint(0, len(vocab))
        yield x
        count +=1
```

I make it a tf.data.Dataset object

```
gen = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(create_generator, 
                                     args=[], 
                                     output_types=tf.int32, 
                                     output_shapes = (), )
```

Now I want to sub-sample items using the **map** method, such that the tf generator would never output any even number.

```
def subsample(x):
    'remove item if it is present in an even number [2,4]'
    
    '''
    #TODO
    '''
    return x
    
gen = gen.map(subsample)
```

How can I achieve this using **map** method?

Answer (score 7):

Shortly no, you cannot filter data using `map`. Map functions apply some transformation to every element of the dataset. What you want is to check every element for some predicate and get only those elements that satisfy the predicate.

And that function is [`filter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter).

So you can do:

```
gen = gen.filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0)
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to use a custom function instead of `lambda`, you can do something like:

```
def filter_func(x):
    if x**2 < 500:
        return True
    return False
gen = gen.filter(filter_func)
```

If this function is passed to `filter` all numbers whose square is less than 500 will be returned.

Comment: Wow! This was helpful. Can I use a custom python function to filter out the elements of the dataset based on some custom rules too?

Comment: The real thing that I want to do is, sub-sample items from an item list, based on their frequency of occurrence. 
An item list can be like [1,3,4,6,1,3,9], now lets say after applying the subsampling, the item list is reduced to [1,3,6,1]. Next thing I want to do is discard all the sequences with length less than 2. If length is >= 2, I want to use  it .

How can I pull this off?

Comment: Yes, as long as your custom function returns boolean value. I will update the answer

Comment: But, the boolean will only decide if that particular dataset element will be filtered or not. I am not sure how can I transform the dataset element using a custom python function, and filter out the sequence(or dataset element) if the sequence length is <2. Can you please help me with this?

Can I even use the filter method to do so?

Comment: for your particular problem, `lambda x: gen.count(x) > 2`. But your `gen` must be a variable in the outer scope.